# Equivalent representations for transformation Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm having trouble creating a transformation matrix between two joints of a robot.

**Background:** I have a robot and these two joints represented by two different coordinate systems, 4 and 5 (4th and 5th joint). If I want to find the transform between the 4th joint's coordinate system and the 5th's is the following an appropriate transformation.

[image]

I know the transformation should follow roughly this format.

1. Rotation about the z-axis of coordinate system 4 by theta4
2. followed by a rotation about the x-axis of -90 degrees
3. **I'm stuck on figuring out the displacement and how the rotations of theta4 and Rx(-90) affect d4, d5.**

So I thought I could represent the translations in another way.

1. If I rotated coordinate system 4 of coordinate system 4 by -90 degrees
2. After the coordinate system has been rotated -90 about x then the translation vector becomes [Tx, Ty, Tz] = [0, d4, d5].
3. Then I rotate about the y-axis by a rotation theta 4.

Would this give me an equivalent translation matrix?

My thought process was I could then append this translation to the rotation matrix in the first portion of my question.

Sum everything up:

R = [Rz Theta4][Rx-90][Unknown Translation]

T = [Rx-90][0,d4,d5][Ry Theta4]

Then combine the two to have a complete transformation matrix from coordinate system 4 to coordinate system 5.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It's easiest to work in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) when you have a sequence of transformations that include translations.

When you want to perform an operation which transforms the point $(x,y,z)$ to the new point $(x^{\prime},y^{\prime},z^{\prime})$, write it as
$$
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}}_{A}\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x^{\prime}\\
y^{\prime}\\
z^{\prime}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is the transformation matrix.

For example,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & T_{x}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & T_{y}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & T_{z}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x+T_{x}\\
y+T_{y}\\
z+T_{z}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
translates the point $(x,y,z)$ to the new point $(x + T_x,y + T_y,z + T_z)$.

Comment: Doesn't order matter? If I translate then rotate won't I get a completely different transformation matrix than the one I intended to get?

Comment: I agree, order *does* matter. If you have to apply $A_1$ first, $A_2$ second, ..., $A_N$ last, then you have $$A_N \cdots A_2 A_1 (x,y,z,1)^\intercal = (x^\prime, y^\prime, z^\prime, 1)^\intercal.$$